# Swift - Wait for a delegate function to finish a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, completion

Suppose I have a function with completion handler and my AppDelegate extends from any notification delegate like this:

```
var flag = false
class AppDelegate: finishWorkingDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
    }

    private func updateData(completion: () -> Void) {
        //wait for delegate
        completion()
    }
    
    //delegate function
    func finishWorking(workComplete: Bool) {
        flag = true
    }
}
```

So my `updateData` function needs to wait until finishWorking delegate method where called to launch completion.

`finishWorking` is triggered when a background task did finish at any time.

`updateData` can be used some where at any moment, like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    updateData() {
        //do some other work
    }
}
```

I used a loop for wait until flag changes to `true` to launch completion

```
func updateData(completion: () -> Void) {
    while !flag {
        //...
    }
    completion()
}
```

But this method freezes the app. So, there is a better solution?

**PD:** I know that I can use the delegate function to do "some other work" but this is a particular case, I made this example code to explain the problem as clear as possible. It needs to be as described.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the work you do in `finishWorking` you shouldn't freeze the app , let the app opens the initial vc and show an activity/loading until the heavy work is done then refresh that vc